# Check that username is unique is throwing Error: unexpected non-void return type in void function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode11

I recently added

```
let username = usernameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                let db = Firestore.firestore()

                db.collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if error == nil && snapshot?.documents != nil {
                        }

                    return "Username has already been taken"
        }
```

to a validatefields() function, placed in a Register View Controller.

Since adding it, the line:

```
return "Username has already been taken"
```

is throwing an "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

The entire function is:

```
func validateFields() -> String? {

    //Check everything is filled in
    if usernameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || firstNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || lastNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
        return "Please fill in all fields"

    }

    //Check if password is secure
    let cleanedPassword = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if Utilities.isPasswordValid(cleanedPassword) == false {
        //Password isn't secure enough
        return "Passwords must contain a minimum of 8 characters, using at least one capital, number and special character (!, ?, @, & etc.)"
    }

      let username = usernameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let db = Firestore.firestore()

            db.collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                if error == nil && snapshot?.documents != nil {
                    }

                return "Username has already been taken"
    }


    return nil
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Please look-up “how to return value from asynchronous function.” This has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/25203556?lq=1

Comment: Make not of what scope you are in when doing this, you're not on the function level but inside a closure inside the function (and a closure is like a function)

Comment: @MartinR We really need some master question that answers this once and for all, and some kind of automation that points people towards it